# Equivalence of ABAP SELECT-OPTIONS in C#

Tags: c#, abap

I am writing a report in C# that will generate an SQL statement to call data in SAP.  In SAP ABAP, there is a command "SELECT-OPTIONS" which will automatically place on a screen a field which automatically has a number of different options to input data.  For example, if you wanted to query a customer master database, you could enter a single customer number, multiple customer numbers, multiple ranges of customer numbers.  Set criteria to include the customer numbers, exclude them, etc.

It is really nice functionality that users are asking me to duplicate but with a C# front end.

I am trying to replicate this a portion of this functionality by using lookup buttons, datagridviews, internal lists, etc.

I was wondering if anyone has done anything similar or if there is a customer class that already exists that does the equivalent.

You probably need to understand SAP ABAP and C# to fully understand the question as it is hard to explain without having to show a lot pictures and using a lot of words.

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is no generic finished product that will do it. In ABAP, this relies on the fact that `select-options` is bound to a variable, data element and domain, which, in turn, has either a valid-values-list (fix or via table) and/or various search helps. So if you need to enter an employee number, you will be able to select the number by name or by email or by department or other criteria. So basically, for each “type of object” that you want to enter there is some sort of input help that has intrinsic knowledge of entered data.

If you are only interested in an “input field” that is able to select an **arbitrary number** of following inputs **at the same time** (without value help dialogs)

- include/exclude single values
- include/exclude range (for sortable values) (42-50 or Bob-Mike)
- include/exclude open ranges (>= 42)
- include/exclude values by pattern (ash*)

Then: I never saw anything like that in any UI other than SAPs DynPro or WebDynpro.

In the end, you end up with a so-called range table, which has four values per line:

- include/exclude
- operation (equals, not equals, less than, between, etc)
- value1
- value2 (only relevant for operations like “between”)

So if you build a UI for that, the user will need to enter something which will end up in this construct.

Comment: Thank for the detailed response.  Make senses.  I will try and build the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try ERPConnect from Theobald Software:

https://theobald-software.com/en/erpconnect/

I didn't find a mention of SELECT-OPTION control in the [brochures](https://theobald-software.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/TS_Produktflyer_EN.pdf) but they claim they have .Net API for core SAP/ABAP tools and interfaces, so you can give a try.